# How to change GridView cell color on row MouseOver

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, gridview, onmouseover

I have a GridView and I want to change the cell color when I MouseOver the row. I tried the following:

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#c8e4b6'");
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='white'");
e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='green'");
e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='white'");
```

The row color changes perfectly. But the cell color changes only when the mouse is moved on that cell.

Is there a way to change the cell color when the mouse is on the **row** instead?

Comment: why you can try in  javascript

Comment: Can you help me doing it please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have to set style of `Cells[1]` in mouse over event handler.

You shouldn't set **onmouseover** and **onmouseout** attribute of the cell, because this will work just when you do mouse over on it, not on the whole row.

The code below will describe more:

I have GridView names **GridView1**, and I have Javascript functions to handle mouse over and mouse out event as the following

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function onMouseOver(rowIndex) {
        var gv = document.getElementById("GridView1");
        var rowElement = gv.rows[rowIndex];
        rowElement.style.backgroundColor = "#c8e4b6";
        rowElement.cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }

    function onMouseOut(rowIndex) {
        var gv = document.getElementById("GridView1");
        var rowElement = gv.rows[rowIndex];
        rowElement.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
        rowElement.cells[1].style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    }
</script>
```

In RowDataBound event handler, try to add attributes **onmouseover** and **onmouseout** to all rows, handled by Javascript functions, **onMouseOver** and **onMouseOut**

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "onMouseOver('" + (e.Row.RowIndex + 1) + "')";
       e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "onMouseOut('" + (e.Row.RowIndex + 1) + "')";
    }
}
```

The GridView tag should be like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ...  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 5):

Use this it will change your cell color

```
if (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    string onmouseoverStyle = "this.style.backgroundColor='blue'";
    string onmouseoutStyle = "this.style.backgroundColor='white'";
    e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("onmouseover",onmouseoverStyle);
    e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("onmouseout",onmouseoutStyle);
}
```

you can modify it according to ur self for row also

you can also use this code

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string onmouseoverStyle = "this.style.backgroundColor='blue'";
        string onmouseoutStyle = "this.style.backgroundColor='white'";
        string onmouseoverStyle1 = "this.style.backgroundColor='green'";
        string onmouseoutStyle1 = "this.style.backgroundColor='white'";
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", onmouseoverStyle1);
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", onmouseoutStyle1);
        e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("onmouseover", onmouseoverStyle);
        e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("onmouseout", onmouseoutStyle);
    }
```

Comment: but first change your row color then your cell color otherwise it will show only your row color

Answer (score 3):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  function SetHeight(txtdesc) {
            txtdesc.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        }
        function out(txtdesc) {
            txtdesc.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        }
</script>

 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtdiscpoint" ForeColor="Black" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="1.10em" 
 TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" onmouseover="SetHeight(this)" onmouseout="out(this)" > </asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works only if i move over the paricular cell. If I move mouse over the row, color of cell does not change

Comment: mouseout you change color

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover","this.originalcolor=this.style.backgroundColor;" + " this.style.backgroundColor='#FDCB0A';");
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The row color changes. But I want to change the colour of particular cell on mouseover.

Comment: Try removing the background color of particular cell on mouse hover and then add the needed background color on mouse out.

Comment: Thats what. I do not know to remove or add colour to particular "CELL" on mouseover on "ROW".

Comment: Check if you find this useful http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-change-GridView-Row-Color-on-Mouseover-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: That changes only row color not cell color

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <style type="text/css">

        #GridView1 tr.rowHover:hover

        {

            background-color: Yellow;

            font-family: Arial;

        }

    </style>

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" RowStyle-CssClass="rowHover" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Link:

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1374/how-to-display-mouseover-effect-in-gridview-rows-using-only-css